# how to get corresponding 'Name' against 'Id' for two dictionary keys

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary in C# like below,

```
        var data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        data.Add("Id", new List<string> { "3", "5", "3" });
        data.Add("Name", new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" });
```

Against each "Id" key, there is a corresponding value in "Name" key.

**note - Name will be unique against each Id**

Now, I need all the values from "Name" for (A & C) for which corresponding "Id" key value is 3.

```
var a = data["Id"].Where(b => b == "3");
```

Or is there any better collection to resolve this issue?

Comment: How are they related, Is the name going to be Unique?

Comment: Yes, Name will be unique for sure

Comment: `var a = data["Id"].Where(b => b == "3");` seems absolutely okay to me.

Comment: but how to get name?

Comment: Do you understand how dictionaries work?

Comment: I'd probably use another structure, maybe `Dictionary<int,List<string>()` so you use the id as key and the names as value

Comment: Try following :  var a = data["Id"].Select((b, i) => new { value = b, index = i }).Where(b => b.value == "3").Select(x => data["Name"][x.index]).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng See my answer for a much more efficient way of doing precisely the same concept.

Comment: Abion: I don't know if your solutions any more efficient then my way.  Zip probably takes more memory resources than a straight lookup/enumeration.

Comment: @jdweng I doubt that `Zip` would cause any memory footprint at all seeing as no part of the query as a whole requires that the entire collection be traversed before continuing. As it is, it would have an identical performance footprint and *maybe* a slightly higher memory footprint than doing this purely with a for loop (since that's basically what it is).

Comment: @jdweng And if nothing else, IMO my method is much more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Zip` method should help you out:

```
var names = data["Id"].Zip(data["Name"], (a,b) => new { Id = a, Name = b})
                      .Where(x => x.Id == 3)
                      .Select(x => x.Name);
```

(Note this will only work if there is guaranteed to be a 1-1 correspondence between the two lists.)

Answer (score 2):

Within the confines you've defined, a more suitable structure would be:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>;
data.Add("3", new List<string> { "A", "C" });
data.Add("5", new List<string> { "B" });
```

Where the key of the dictionary is the ID, and the value is a list of names matching that ID.

Answer (score 1):

According to your example data, Index of `Id` and `Name` are same in the `Dictionary`. So you have to find all index according to your condition then get all Name by using those Index.

Please check this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        data.Add("Id", new List<string> { "3", "5", "3" });
        data.Add("Name", new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" });

        //var a = data["Id"].FindIndex(b => b == "3");

        int[] indexs = data["Id"].Select((b,i) => b == "3" ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();

        foreach(var index in indexs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data["Name"][Convert.ToInt16(index)]);
        }   
    }
}
```

You can check output in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a8prPE).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the way you are currently storing these values.

One alternative can be to to use Dictionary and store Names in Key and Id in Value.

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
data.Add("A", 3);
data.Add("B", 5);
data.Add("C", 3);
```

This would be if You also want to sometimes use Name to access the Id, but if you are only going to use Ids to find names, go with the solution in the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just work with a regular Dictionary?

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]> {{"3", new[] {"A", "C"}}, {"5", new[] {"B"}}};
        var a = dict.Where(x => x.Key == "3");
```

Comment: How can there be 2 records in there with the same key '3'?

Comment: Whoops my bad, didn't see that it wasn't unique. Fixed it now.

Comment: At this point, the `Where` is complete overkill. Just use `dict["3"]`.